# Unable to find items via route - Couldn't find Affiliate with 'id'=

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Currently fetching some items ([REST Client](https://github.com/rest-client/rest-client)) from this external API in the background ([DelayedJob](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job_active_record)) and then saving them to the database. The plan is to check using a Rails route whether or not the items have been saved to the database, ie. when it's safe to start pulling them in via Ajax.

But what's wrong with my `check_items_loaded` route? I thought it was supposed to look for `url`, not `id`?

```
Started GET "/check_items_loaded" 2015-06-06 00:43:03 +0000
Processing by MainController#check_items_loaded as */*
  Affiliate Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "affiliates".* FROM "affiliates" WHERE "affiliates"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", nil]]
Completed 404 Not Found in 52ms

ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find Affiliate with 'id'=):
  app/controllers/main_controller.rb:8:in `check_items_loaded'
```

**Live app which you can run on the fly**: http://runnable.com/VXIdQ6KuRrYPdhKs/rest-client-ajax

**routes.rb**

```
get '/check_items_loaded', to: 'main#check_items_loaded', as: :check_items_loaded
```

**main_controller.rb**

```
class MainController < ApplicationController
  def index
    # Delay fetching
    @products = Affiliate.delay.fetch
  end

  def check_items_loaded
    @items_status = Affiliate.find(params[:url])
    respond_to do |wants|
      wants.js
    end
  end
end
```

**affiliate.rb**

```
require "rest_client"

class Affiliate < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.fetch
    response = RestClient::Request.execute(
      :method => :get,
      :url => "http://api.shopstyle.com/api/v2/products?pid=uid7849-6112293-28&fts=women&offset=0&limit=10"
    )

    @products = JSON.parse(response)["products"].map do |product|
      product = OpenStruct.new(product)
      affiliate = Affiliate.find_or_create_by(:name => product.name, :url => product.url)
      affiliate.save
    end
  end
end
```

**20150604213141_add_items_to_affiliates.rb**

```
class AddItemsToAffiliates < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    change_table(:affiliates) do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.string :url
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you run `#find(foo)`, ActiveRecord treats the value stored in `foo` as the id column no matter what. What you actually want instead of `Affiliate.find(params[:url])` is `Affiliate.where(url: params[:url])` in order to search for the matching url parameter.

Comment: Would you happen to know why I can't call `@items_status` from the view so I can check if REST Client is done fetching them? Please see: https://gist.github.com/dt1973/b57d84bf39a75ea47e9b

Comment: Created http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30688332/use-route-to-check-when-items-are-done-how-to-reuse-this-for-view as well.