# Use route to check from view when items are done

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Using a route to check from JS when [REST Client](https://github.com/rest-client/rest-client) is done fetching items from this external API in the background ([DelayedJob](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job)). The route part works fine, but how do I reuse the same `@items_status` from view so that Ajax can actually load the items and insert them when done?

**Live app which you can run on the fly**: http://runnable.com/VXIdQ6KuRrYPdhKs/rest-client-ajax (https://gist.github.com/dt1973/b57d84bf39a75ea47e9b)

**index.html.erb**

```
<!-- THIS ALWAYS RETURNS FALSE EVEN WHEN TRUE -->

<% if @items_status %>
  <div class="products">
    <% @products.each do |product| %>
      <div class="product">
        <%= link_to product.name, product.url %>
      </div>
    <% end %>
  </div>
<% else %>
  <div class="products processing">
    <p>Currently fetching.. come back later</p>

    <!-- Fetch via Ajax later -->

  </div>
<% end %>
```

**check_items_loaded.js.erb**

```
<!-- This seems to return true properly though -->

alert("<%= @items_status %>");
```

**routes.rb**

```
get '/check_items_loaded', to: 'main#check_items_loaded', as: :check_items_loaded
```

**main_controller.rb**

```
class MainController < ApplicationController
  def index
    # Delay fetching
    @products = Affiliate.delay.fetch
  end

  def check_items_loaded
    @items_status = Affiliate.where(url: params[:url]).exists?
    respond_to do |wants|
      wants.js
    end
  end
end
```

**affiliate.rb**

```
require "rest_client"

class Affiliate < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.fetch
    response = RestClient::Request.execute(
      :method => :get,
      :url => "http://api.shopstyle.com/api/v2/products?pid=uid7849-6112293-28&fts=women&offset=0&limit=10"
    )

    @products = JSON.parse(response)["products"].map do |product|
      product = OpenStruct.new(product)
      affiliate = Affiliate.find_or_create_by(:name => product.name, :url => product.url)
      affiliate.save
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to reuse the route used for checking whether the items are fetched or not, rather than the instance `@items_status` from view.

In your Ajax part, you basically have to keep on querying the route to check if it's done fetching, and when it's done you have to issue a request to another route to get the fetched items back to the page.

So make another route like `get_items_fetched` and I think the best response would be a json data containing the items. For instance :

```
def get_fetched_items
  respond_to do |format|
    format.json do 
      render json: @products
    end
  end
end
```

You should get the json data at `/get_items_fetched.json`.

**Update 1 :**

The right way to fetch the item status and items, will be like :

AJAX part :

- First change setTimeout to setInterval, so it automatically keeps on polling for the item_status. But if you have your own reasons to use setTimeout then you can ignore this.

  ```
   poll: function() {
     console.log('Ran `poll`');
     // Change here, setTimeout to setInterval.
     window.pollInterval = setInterval(this.request, 3000);
   },
  ```
- Secondly check for the item_status returned for the polling request and don't retry in the error part.

  ```
  request: function() {

    console.log('Ran `request`');
    $.ajax({
      url: "/check_items_loaded",
      type: "GET",

      // Change here ! Added the checking of the item status returned.
      // Why ? Previsouly it wasn't checking at all. So if the request was
      // successful, it meant the items_status was also true.
      success: function(data){
        // Note if the data has the json MIME type, it'll be automatically
        // converted to a JavaScript object.
        if(data.item_status == true) {
          console.log('Items now ready');
          $.restClient.addItems();

          // Now you don't have to poll anymore, so clear interval.
          clearInterval(window.pollInterval);
        }
        else 
          console.log('Fetching going on ...');
      },
      error: function() {
        console.log('Request was not completed successfully.');
      }
    });
  },
  ```
- Next, parse the HTML you are getting in the response of `addItems`. By default, if the response is HTML it gives you it as plain text.

  ```
  addItems: function() {
    console.log('Ran `addItems`');

    var dataUrl = '/';

    $.get(dataUrl, function(data) {
      // Parsing it first.
      var html = $.parseHTML(data);
      $(html).find('.product').appendTo($('body'));
      console.log(html);
    });

    console.log('New items were added');
  }
  ```
- Now on the back end, `/check_items_done` route part :

  ```
   def check_items_loaded
    @items_status = Affiliate.where(url: params[:url]).exists?
    render json: {item_status: @item_status}
   end
  ```

Comment: Hi! That sounds like a plan, thank you! 1. What should I now put in my view? 2. Why JSON and not just the normal HTML way? 3. Please see my gist to see how I plan to do the Ajax part. Does it look okay?

Comment: In your view I think you can create an empty identifiable placeholder, maybe a div, so that you can build the products in there once you retrieve the fetched products from the back. Yeah I'm checking the AJAX code right now.

Comment: Awesome! And then somehow assemble the JSON into HTML inside the Ajax success code right?

Comment: Ah yeah I just checked now, so you are trying to fetch the products from the html page you get from '/', it's okay I think. I checked the AJAX part in gist last that's why. Think it'll be okay, but will it work just like that ? I mean you will have to parse the html page returned before querying it with jquery.

Comment: Lets just try the current way first. Btw, also the `success` part of your `request` of `restClient` always returns true. I mean the success event means the request has been completed successfully, it doesn't mean that the returned items_status is true.

Comment: The `$(html).find('.product').appendTo($('body'));` should work I think. Is it okay if we try HTML first? Because I use HTML for some other Ajax stuff in my app and it'd be cool to keep things consistent. Thanks for pointing out it'll always return success, I had no idea.

Comment: To sum things up -- 1. how to render the view based on items_status or similar, and 2. how to do the Ajax success event only if items_status is true?

Comment: Yeah I will update my answer now with the solution to those parts. Btw, sorry for the late response I had to give away my system for sometime.

Comment: Greetings! No probs, fell asleep myself (long day). So, 1. `<% if @items_status %>` in the view still won't return true hence there are no products for the Ajax to parse, please see the updated gist or try the live app, 2. Do we really need JSON? Are you sure it doesn't complicate things rather than simplify them? 3. Do we still need `get_fetched_items`?, 4. Why use `parseHTML` and not just parse the raw HTML?, 5. Yep, using `setTimeout` because apparently `setInterval` is evil (http://railscasts.com/episodes/229-polling-for-changes), 6. Maybe we should move to chat.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79885/discussion-between-limekin-and-flynt-hamlock).